# How can I use pager.setCurrentItem() inside a fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

I created many  fragments, Fragment1 , Fragment2.. , Fragment50 Inside the first  fragment with listener method I want to call Fragment40. But I didnt manage. inside the listener these lines runs

```
pager.setCurrentItem(0);
pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
But pager.setCurrentItem(40); not run. Gives errors. Any help please?
//First Fragment01
//I want to call Fragment40
public class Frag_2 extends  Fragment implements 
        OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
//....................................................
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
final ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
View txtdersHakkinda1 = (View) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtDersHakkinda1);
txtdersHakkinda1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem()+40);    // not run
//  pager.setCurrentItem(0);    //runs
//  pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
//  pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
}
} );    
//......................................................................
}
/////////////////////// If many fragments --> FragmentStatePagerAdapter /////////////
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
private List<Fragment> fragments;
public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
super(fm);
this.fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
fragments.add(new Frag_1<Object>());
fragments.add(new Frag_2());
fragments.add(new Frag_3());
fragments.add(new Frag_4());
 .....................
fragments.add(new Frag_50());
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
return fragments.get(position);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
return fragments.size();
}
}
```

Comment: post code for this fragment, because no one can help you without it

Comment: I am recruit, trying to add codes

Comment: just copy it as usual, then select it and press ctrl + k

Comment: callback to the Activity: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 0):

add this methods to your adapter :

```
 @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        registeredFragments.remove(position);
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }

    public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {
        return registeredFragments.get(position);
    }
```

And the you cant get items like this: `adapater.getRegisteredFragment(viewPager.getCurrentItem())`

Comment: I added your methods and SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<Fragment>()  to my adapter. Now what must I do to call Fragment40.class with a clickview?

Comment: You don't need an array, you should just call adapater.getRegisteredFragment(pager.getCurrentItem + 40) instead of pager.getCurrentItem()+40 and then you can use 40 fragment

Comment: pageAdapter.getRegisteredFragment(pager.getCurrentItem()+2); gives nullpoint ..  In MainActivity  I defined.
 //   Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter. 
  fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
  pageAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(fragmentManager);
  final ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
  pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
  pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);

Comment: maybe you should post your new code into question, because it's hard to undertand now